# Accessing remote server database from iphone?

Tags: iphone, database, remote-server

Is there any way to access the remote server database from the iphone? except the way of json or by xml. Can i get sample code?

Comment: This is a potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373011/what-is-the-best-way-of-connecting-to-a-remote-server-database-to-retrieve-data-f and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947835/iphone-connecting-to-database-over-internet, among others.

Answer (score 1):

Build a web service front end.

Comment: can i get any sample? because i can't get clearly about webservice?

Answer (score 0):

If your server has been developed to handle requests and send response, u can use NSMutableURLRequest and achieve data. You will receive pure HTML data and then u have to parse it.